# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord join statement dropping '[' from the ON clause

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, activerecord

Using Codeigniter (v1.7.2) Active Record Class to query a MSSQL Database (external DB, I don't control table or field names)

The following Code:

```
$this->db->select('[Key Field], MemberInfo.OtherField');
$this->db->limit(10);
$this->db->from('primaryTable');
$this->db->join('MemberInfo', '[Member Number] = Member_Number', 'left');
$this->db->where('[Member Number]  = 573');
$this->db->where('[Incident Date] BETWEEN '. $DateStart . ' AND ' . $DateEnd);
```

Produces the following Query (which has a syntax error)

```
SELECT  TOP 10 [Key Field], MemberInfo.OtherField
FROM primaryTable
LEFT JOIN MemberInfo ON Member Number] = Member_Number
WHERE [Member Number] = '573'
AND [Incident Date] BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2012-07-19
```

Note the JOIN clause, which is missing the opening '[' on the field name

I tried using double quotes, which yielded the same result.

Anyone have ideas, is this a known bug in 1.7.2 (which I know is old, working up updating)?

**UPDATE**
issue is present in 2.1.2 also

Accepted answer below is also the fix for 2.1.2: change the regex check in the JOIN function to look for the opening `[`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the parameter `ON`. There does not exist an integrated solution in the framework (not in version 2).

You have 2 options:

1. [Altering the core of the library active_record](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/428702387ca071db4686ec6d6c60bd35b01c33e4)
2. Write the query in a complete chain with concatenations using [$this->db->query()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html);

Comment: in v1.7.2 (which I am using) the regex in the `function join` needs to be modified to be: `/([\[\w\.]+)([\W\s]+)(.+)/` in order to capture the first open bracket.